# div content container to have 80% of the space and hang to the left

Tags: html, css

See, I have this:

http://pasteht.ml/r9x7G (Source : https://gist.github.com/AtomicCreeper/27c950967210959b47b1)

I want div menubar to have 20% of the space (minus the margins) and hang to the right

I want div content container to have 80% of the space (minus the margin) and hang to the left

I'd like the two divs to be side by side in the container. The percentage there is percentage of the divs space. I;d like the divs to have 80% of the available space in the page.

What am I doing wrong? I'm honestly clueless

Comment: And because we all love JSFiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/WMxn4/

Comment: I originally went there but I can't paste my entire source in there and I'm too lazy to seperate CSS and hTML and all that. It simply won't let me insert a complete page :(

Comment: ....I just did it. Does it look that difficult? You copy+paste your CSS (which looked like maybe 20 lines) into the CSS block, and then your html between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags in the HTML spot.

Comment: Problem is that you can't insert bootstrap.css so it looks bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.tablebarz {
width: 20%;
margin-bottom: 30px;
/* margin-top: 50px; */
/* margin-left: 20px; */
/* margin-right: 5px; */
/* display: inline-block; */
float: right;
}

.roundedcontainer {
/* position: absoulute; */
margin-right: 25px;
border: 2px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 74%;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I'm still curious as to what I did wrong

Comment: Just floated the two divs to the appropriate sides of the container. I've also adjusted the .roundedcontainer style - the position is not needed.